# String splitting multiple lines in text file

Tags: c++

So i have a text file that reads

> ```
> [0, 0]-564-John_doe
>
> [1, 3]-533-Mary_sue
>
> [2, 5]-666-samuel
> ```

etc...
etc...

The delimiter is `-` and be able to store all these information into a vector of strings.

What i have tried is

```
vector<string>tokens;
string token;
string delimiter = "-";
string token;

size_t pos_start = 0l pos_end, delim_len = delimiter.length();
ifstream cityText(filename);
string line;

while (cityText >> line) {
           token = line.substr(pos_start, pos_end - pos_start);
           pos_start = pos_end + delim_len;
           tokens.push_back(token);
    }

    return (tokens);


}
```

Need some help or recommendations to output my vector into

`[ [0, 0], 564, John_doe, [1, 3], 533, Mary_sue... ]`

The biggest problem i am facing is the space in between the `[0, 0]` and the spaces after each name

Comment: .... regex? I know I know ... but ... idk, I would go for it. (funny how C++ has regex but doesn't have a decent split function)

Comment: Rather use `while (std::getline(cityText, line)) {` to read a whole line from the text file. Why didn't you follw that advice when I recommended you to do this last time? Next step is to use `std::istringstream` and split the string again using `std::getline()` with the delimiter of your choice. Stop asking those low researched questions over and over again here please.

Comment: `while (cityText >> line) {` doesn't do what you think it does. That doesn't read a whole line, but stops the input after the 1st whitespace character seen. This seems to be the whole problem with your source code, and you seemingly didn't recognize that, neither from already given advice, nor from thoroughly debugging your code. I am afraid we can't help you any further.

Answer (score 0):

As rightly suggested by [πάντα ῥεῖ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1413395/%CF%80%CE%AC%CE%BD%CF%84%CE%B1-%E1%BF%A5%CE%B5%E1%BF%96), you may do something like this:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::string str;
    ifstream fin("path to file");

    cout << "[ ";
    // get the input from the file till end of line in str
    while (getline(fin, str)) {
        std::string record[3];
        std::istringstream sstr(str);

        // extract record one by one from sstr using - as delimiter
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i ++) {
            getline(sstr, record[i], '-');
        }

        // Process the record. You may do something else also.
        for (auto &ele: record) {
            cout << ele << ", ";
        }
    }

    cout << "]";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @j.test Did this answer your question?